# JQuery Template With Image Zoom

Tags: jquery, image, templates, zooming

I'm looking for a JQuery template that will look the image viewer seen here:
http://www.murrayandmurray.co.uk/casestudy/country-life/

I can't find anything like it on the stock sites.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
-Katie

Answer (score 0):

They're using a WP plug-in called "nextgen gallery". The code for it is here: http://code.google.com/p/nextgen-gallery/source/browse/trunk/js/ngg.slideshow.js?r=811

Comment: Thanks, but I was really looking for a Jquery similar to it. The preview doesn't have any tabs on it either.